# Происхождение слова «лавэ»

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова «лавэ»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Лавэ» произошло от цыганского «ловэ», что значит «деньги».

История этого слова хорошо описана [здесь](http://www.russ.ru/pole/LV).
Цитаты оттуда:

> В Россию цыгане попали в XV-XVI веках, принеся на новые территории свою культуру и язык, а вместе с ним и слово ловэ, которое можно встретить, например, в переписке Сергея Николаевича и Льва Николаевича Толстых: "Напиши мне об себе поподробнее, как все - шукр или пашукр? требицы или на ловы?" - "прекрасно или не прекрасно? нужненько или нет денег?" (Шаповал В.В. "Цыганская речь у Льва Толстого"). К слову, Сергей Николаевич с 1850 года состоял в гражданском браке с хоровой цыганкой Марьей Шишкиной (обвенчались они в 1867-м), и именно он учил Льва Николаевича говорить на цыганском языке, слова из которого будут нередко возникать в их переписке.

…

> Первые упоминания о лавэ как слове из воровского жаргона относятся к 20-30-м годам.

…

> В конце 80-х - начале 90-х слово лавэ вошло в более широкие массы наряду с другими криминальными словами…

…

> Декриминализация слова лавэ происходит во второй половине 90-х, когда из уголовного оно превращается в просто "модное словечко".

[Большой словарь русских поговорок](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/4467/%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%92%D0%AD) согласен с этой этимологией.

Comment: И что теперь???

Answer (score 0):

Корень слова ивритский.
לווה- заемшик денег .